How to generate the correct manifest.mpd structure?
ffmpeg -i {file} -deadline good -movflags +faststart -map_metadata -1 \
    -c:a libopus -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -map 0:a:0 -b:a:0 128k \
    -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-1:144 -b:v:0 60k \
    -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:1 scale=-1:240 -b:v:0 120k \
    -init_seg_name "init-$RepresentationID$.$ext$"\
    -media_seg_name "sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$" \
    -dash_segment_type webm \
    -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 9 \
    -adaptation_sets "id=0, streams=v id=0, streams=a" \
    -f dash manifest.mpd

At the exit I get: manifest.mpd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    type="static"
    mediaPresentationDuration="PT8M18.9S"
    maxSegmentDuration="PT9.0S"
    minBufferTime="PT32.0S">
    <ProgramInformation>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <ServiceDescription id="0">
    </ServiceDescription>
    <Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" frameRate="30/1" maxWidth="1934" maxHeight="1080" par="16:9">
            <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/webm" codecs="vp09.00.11.08" bandwidth="60000" width="258" height="144" sar="128:129">
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" initialization="init-$RepresentationID$.webm" media="sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.webm" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="7" d="12800" r="37" />
                        <S d="12466" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
            <Representation id="2" mimeType="video/webm" codecs="vp09.00.20.08" bandwidth="150000" width="430" height="240" sar="128:129">
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" initialization="init-$RepresentationID$.webm" media="sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.webm" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="7" d="16000" r="30" />
                        <S d="2866" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="audio" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true">
            <Representation id="0" mimeType="audio/webm" codecs="opus" bandwidth="128000" audioSamplingRate="48000">
                <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" initialization="init-$RepresentationID$.webm" media="sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.webm" startNumber="1">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="0" d="9001" />
                        <S d="9000" r="53" />
                        <S d="3934" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>

How to correctly execute a command so that the output is the following manifest structure? Downloaded from the official site. She is faithful, I don’t understand that...
https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb_30fps/bbb_with_multiple_tiled_thumbnails.mpd
<MPD mediaPresentationDuration="PT634.566S" minBufferTime="PT2.00S" profiles="urn:hbbtv:dash:profile:isoff-live:2012,urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 DASH-MPD.xsd">
 <BaseURL>./</BaseURL>
 <Period>
  <AdaptationSet id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" contentType="video" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1" par="16:9">
      <SegmentTemplate duration="120" timescale="30" media="$RepresentationID$/$RepresentationID$_$Number$.m4v" startNumber="1" initialization="$RepresentationID$/$RepresentationID$_0.m4v"/>
      <Representation id="bbb_30fps_320x180_400k" codecs="avc1.64000d" bandwidth="507246" width="320" height="180" frameRate="30" sar="1:1" scanType="progressive"/>
      <Representation id="bbb_30fps_480x270_600k" codecs="avc1.640015" bandwidth="759798" width="480" height="270" frameRate="30" sar="1:1" scanType="progressive"/>
  </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet id="2" mimeType="audio/mp4" contentType="audio" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
      <Accessibility schemeIdUri="urn:tva:metadata:cs:AudioPurposeCS:2007" value="6"/>
      <Role schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:role:2011" value="main"/>
      <SegmentTemplate duration="192512" timescale="48000" media="$RepresentationID$/$RepresentationID$_$Number$.m4a" startNumber="1" initialization="$RepresentationID$/$RepresentationID$_0.m4a"/>
      <Representation id="bbb_a64k" codecs="mp4a.40.5" bandwidth="67071" audioSamplingRate="48000">
          <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
      </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>

